Get_it from background service ? Object/factory with type <> is not registered inside GetIt
I'm trying to do an Flutter app where there is a background service running, and playing audio files when in a specific GPS location.
But I can't retrieve my AudioHandler instance from just_audio in my background service.
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type AudioHandler is not registered inside GetIt.  (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance; Did you forget to register it?)
Packages : get_it, audio_service & flutter_background_service.
Simplified code :

Future<void> main() async {
  GetIt.I.registerSingleton<AudioHandler>(await initAudioService());
  var test = GetIt.I.get<AudioHandler>(); <-- works.
  initializeBackgroundService();
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MapScreen()));
}

Future<FlutterBackgroundService> initializeBackgroundService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart
      [...]
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      onForeground: onStart
      [...]
    ),
  );
  [...]
  return service;
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  [...]
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
    [...]
    var test = GetIt.I.get<AudioHandler>(); <-- doesn't work.
  });
}


I already read most of thread where GetIt can't retrieve the instance. The object seems registered as I can call it in my main app code, but can't in my background service.
